# Android see stored image file from application

Tags: android, flutter, file, directory

I've made an application in which the user takes a picture and it is stored in the app. Here is the flutter code for what I am doing.

```
XFile? rawImage = await takePicture();
File imageFile = File(rawImage!.path);
int currentUnix = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // PUTTING IT HERE
String fileFormat = imageFile.path.split('.').last;
await imageFile.copy('${directory.path}/$currentUnix.$fileFormat',);
```

How do I access the application documents directory on android? I want to see where the images are stored.

I've checked /apps/myapp but I can't find any files there. I've also checked documents. I'm using the files app to locate these.

Where can I find the images?

Comment: Ah nowadays it's sooo easy to do complex things like this. Back in my day (I believe it was the 1970's), we had to literally wire our computer funny in order to get a basic scent of perfume from our computer. Really makes me think back to a time when the suns were frolicking.

Comment: `application in which the user takes a picture and it is stored in the app. ` No your app cannot store pictures in itself. Only in a storage location of the device.